# Expressions to calculate Vacancy Rate

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Assuming that I need generate a SSRS report to show vacancy rate by district which return values below:

```
  [Availability]    [District1]     [District2]   [District3]   [Position_Count]
Available Positions      2               4             2               8           
No Available Positions   2               6             8              12 
Total                    4               10           10              16  
Vacancy rate           0.5              0.4          0.2              0.5
```

The row groups are Availability and the column groups are district.

I create two datasets: 'Main' and 'Available Positions'.

The sql for 'Main' dataset:

```
select COUNT(Positions) as Position_Count, Availability, District
from Job_Positions GROUP BY Availability, District
```

The sql for 'Available Positions':

```
select COUNT(Positions) as Position_Count, Availability, District
from Job_Positions where Availability='Available Positions'
GROUP BY Availability, District
```

I wrote expression for Total vacancy rate: =Sum(Fields!Position_Count.Value, "Available Positions")/Sum(Fields!Position_Count.Value, "Main")

My question is how I can write expressions to calulate Vacancy Rates for each district.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need the Available positions rate?

Comment: Yes. Vacancy rate is available positions rate

Comment: What is the dataset you are using in the tablix?

Comment: In the report, I only use two datasets: 'Main' and 'Available Positions' which I used to calculate the total vacancy Rate (Available Position Rate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=Sum(
IIF(Fields!Availability.Value="Available Positions",Fields!Position_Count.Value,0)
)/Sum(Fields!Position_Count.Value,"District")
```

Replace `"District"` by the actual name of the Column group district.

**UPDATE:**

I've recreated your dataset and used a matrix with this data arrangement:

[image]

It is not tested but should work, let me know if this helps.

For `Total` I used this expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!Position_count.Value,"District")
```

For `Rate` I used the same expression as I proposed initially:

```
=Sum(
IIF(Fields!Availability.Value="Available Positions",Fields!Position_count.Value,0)
)/Sum(Fields!Position_count.Value,"District")
```

> Note I am only using `Main` dataset.

It will produce this matrix:

[image]

Comment: It did not work. I created more datasets for each district. The SQL is: select COUNT(Positions) as Position_Count, Availability, District
from Job_Positions where district='District1'
GROUP BY Availability, District . I tried =IIF(Fields!District.Value = "District1",Fields!Position_Count.Value/sum(Fields!Position_Count.Value,"District1"),Fields!Position_Count.Value/sum(Fields!Position_Count.Value,"District2")) , the results are still not correct but it gave me three different number for vacancy rate for each district.

Comment: You don't need multiple dataset to achieve this. Using my expression it throws an error or show wrong data?

Comment: @Cindy, check my update, I am only using the main dataset.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, It is my mistake. Your answer is correct. Thank you so much for your answer and the update!

Comment: @Cindy : You are welcome, If my answer solved your question issue you can select it as correct by right clicking the _correct_ symbol in the left side of my answer. [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I did, Thank you Alejandro!